# Why was the small council so happy for Tyrion to become the Master of Coin?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S03E02, Tywin Lannister names Tyrion the Master of Coin, followed by Varys and Cersei quickly smirking at Tyrion (and Pycelle being enthusiastic about the development).

Why were they so happy for Tyrion to take on Master of Coin? Just because it's maybe such a boring job? Wouldn't the Master of Coin have a great amount of power in King's Landing, given that wars, etc., are funded and at the discretion of the Master of Coin?

Comment: On top of the good answers provided, I just wanted to note that this was an especially cunning move since it allowed Tywin to distance Littlefinger from the throne, who always served his own interests first, while simultaneously filling the void of his absence with a Lannister. It was a masterful power play that only Littlefinger (judging by his reaction) seemed to understand, and further solidified their family's power over the throne.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firstly, the Master of Coin isn't seen as a particularly prestigious position; in S04E08, Bronze Yohn Royce insults Peter Baelish by saying it has

> Always been a grubby job. Why not let a grubby man do it?

Secondly, Tyrion freely admits that he has no knowledge of how money works beyond spending it, and is thus particularly ill-suited to the job. Those around the council table do seem to take pleasure in other people's discomfort, especially when it comes to Tyrion.

Lastly, with regards to it being a position of power, under Robert Baratheon this was plainly true as Robert spent prodigiously and freely, which helped Baelish to improve his own situation. With Tywin ultimately now in control, its likely that Tyrion would have to find money at his father's direction and without much autonomy.

Comment: Additionally, the Crown is knee deep in debt, and the MoC would have to inherit the burden of dealing with that debt.

Answer (score 11):

It's possible there's also a subtext here where "insiders" have some awareness that the bill for Baelish's spending under Robert Baratheon will eventually come due - and when it does, whoever's sitting in the seat of the Master of Coin will take the blame and the fall for it.

Answer (score 5):

None of the other councilors (save Varys) have any love or respect for Tyrion.

Cersei generally despises him, Pycell was imprisoned by him, and Littlefinger sees him as nuisance to his schemes.

Cersei sarcastically quips:

> I have no doubt you will prove equal to the challenge.

She and the others are hoping that he is not. They are hoping for his failure that way Tyrion will be removed from the council completely never to be a thorn in their side again.